# Local Node.js gives back "request is not defined", but online node website works perfectly

Tags: node.js, api

I'm still new at node.js and I'm trying to get my small API to return data. As you can see [here](https://repl.it/repls/FreshHastyGnudebugger)

the code works perfectly on this online editor, but locally while running node it gives an error.

My code:

```
var http = require('http');

var options = { method: 'GET',
   url: 'https://eftelingapi.herokuapp.com/attractions',
   headers: 
  {'cache-control': 'no-cache'};

 request(options, function (error, response, body) {
   if (error) throw new Error(error);

   var jsonData = JSON.parse(body);


   console.log(jsonData.AttractionInfo[0]);
 });
```

The error:

```
ReferenceError: request is not defined
at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/ricky/Desktop/eftelApp/app.js:9:1)
at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:707:30)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:718:10)
at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:605:32)
at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:544:12)
at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:536:3)
at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:760:12)
at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:308:19)
at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:878:3)
```

Hopefully anyone knows what's wrong in my code or what I can fix on my local node? I've installed the "request" package already, but that didn't seem to do it

Comment: In the online editor you have `var request = require("request");` I don't see it in the code you posted here.

Comment: You're right Roland Starke, it's a typo while experimenting with code. Thanks for pointing it out!

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
http.request()
```

check  [this](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_http_request_options_callback) for more info.